# Receive foreign UDP Broadcast with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, udp, udpclient

I have a device in the network at `192.168.123.204` which broadcasts UDP datagrams(Artnet) as `2.168.123.204` to `2.255.255.255:6454`. (The network address is `192.168.123.204` but the datagram is sent with `2.168.123.204` as source.) The address `2.255.255.255`  can't be changed (no setting for that).

My Python script runs on the device `192.168.123.148`. I can receive the datagrams there with wireshark: but a Python socket bound to `0.0.0.0:6454` can't receive them. Binding it to `2.168.123.204` or `2.255.255.255` does not work. The script is working, since I can receive Packets from `127.0.0.1`.

If it can't be solved with Python can I redirect the UDP broadcast with iptables (linux)?

Network:
        <kbd>Router 192.168.123.1</kbd>
          /   \ 
<kbd>Broadcaster: 192.168.123.204</kbd> <kbd>Script: 192.168.123.148</kbd>

basic script:

```
import socket
import asyncio


HOST, PORT = 'localhost', 6454


class SyslogProtocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def connection_made(self, transport) -> "Used by asyncio":
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr) -> "Main entrypoint for processing message":
        # Here is where you would push message to whatever methods/classes you want.
      
        print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(SyslogProtocol, local_addr=('0.0.0.0', PORT))
    loop.run_until_complete(t) # Server starts listening
    loop.run_forever()
```

full script:

```
#import pygame
from ctypes import *
import socket
import asyncio
import os, random

class ArtNetPackage(LittleEndianStructure):
    PORT = 0x1936
    _fields_ = [("id", c_char * 8),
                ("opcode", c_ushort),
                ("protverh", c_ubyte),
                ("protver", c_ubyte),
                ("sequence", c_ubyte),
                ("physical", c_ubyte),         
                ("universe", c_ushort),
                ("lengthhi", c_ubyte),
                ("length", c_ubyte),
                ("payload", c_ubyte * 512)]
    
    def get_length(self):
        return self.lengthhi*256+self.length
        
    def __init__(self,data=b''):
        if len(data) == 0:
            self.id = b"Art-Net"
            self.opcode = 0x5000
            self.protver = 14
            self.universe = 0
            self.lengthhi = 2
        else:
            self.id = data[:8]
            self.opcode = data[8]+data[9]*256
            if self.opcode == 0x5000:
                self.protverh = data[10]
                self.protver = data[11]
                self.sequence = data[12]
                self.physical = data[13]
                self.universe = data[14]+data[15]*256
                self.lengthhi = data[16]
                self.length = data[17]
                self.payload = (c_ubyte * 512).from_buffer_copy(
                        data[18:530])#.ljust(512,b'\x00'))

#pygame.init()

HOST, PORT = 'localhost', 6454


class SyslogProtocol(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def connection_made(self, transport) -> "Used by asyncio":
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr) -> "Main entrypoint for processing message":
        # Here is where you would push message to whatever methods/classes you want.
        try:
            dmx = ArtNetPackage(data)
            if not dmx.opcode == 0x5000:
                return
            print(dmx.payload[0])
        except:
            print("error")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(SyslogProtocol, local_addr=('0.0.0.0', PORT))
    loop.run_until_complete(t) # Server starts listening
    loop.run_forever()
```

interfaces:

```
$ ip a
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.123.148/24 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 86393sec preferred_lft 86393sec
    inet6 XXXXXXXX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[image: Wireshark Protocol]

Comment: I am not a networking expert, but what I feel you are doing is not correct. You are currently listening to packets targeted to you. What you need is to listen to raw packets. For that you can use https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/ `LiveCapture` or you can use this example https://www.uv.mx/personal/angelperez/files/2018/10/sniffers_texto.pdf. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Make up your mind. Either '[it] broadcasts UDP datagrams ... to 2.255.255.255:6454' *or* 'the datagram is sent to 2.168.123.204'. Not both at the same time.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your wireshark packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misread your question, you are dealing with broadcast not multicast addresses. Your problem is that you do not have the [SO_BROADCAST](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) flag sent

> IPv4 addresses are divided into unicast, broadcast and multicast
> addresses. Unicast addresses specify a single interface of a host,
> broadcast addresses specify all hosts on a network and multicast
> addresses address all hosts in a multicast group. **Datagrams to
> broadcast addresses can be only sent or received when the SO_BROADCAST
> socket flag is set.** In the current implementation, connection-oriented
> sockets are only allowed to use unicast addresses.

There is an explicit example [here](https://gist.github.com/yluthu/4f785d4546057b49b56c). The most important part being:

```
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        print('started')
        self.transport = transport
        sock = transport.get_extra_info("socket")
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        self.broadcast()
```

You will also need to add an address on that subnet to the interface. This is very simple just enter:

```
ip addr add 2.255.255.254/8 dev eth1
```

This assumes that the broadcast is on 2.0.0.0/8, the interface name is `eth1` and that 2.255.255.254 is not taken by another host.

Comment: He shouldn't need to run the "ip addr" configuration command if he's already receiving packets in wireshark.  The SO_BROADCAST is only necessary when *sending* packets and not receiving them.  I demonstrated the ability to receive without setting that flag in the code in my answer.  Where did you get your quote?  The quote from your SO_BROADCAST link reads: "SO_BROADCAST  Set or get the broadcast flag.  **When enabled, datagram sockets are allowed to send packets to a broadcast address**.  This option has no effect on stream-oriented sockets."

Comment: @MarkH depending on how smart a switch is, you can see many packets that your kernel/nic will drop because they are not destined for you (first the dst MAC is checked for layer 2 and then dst IP for Layer 3). Ignoring the MAC/ARP, your kernel will not accept a subnet broadcast packet unless it comes in on an  interface with an IP on that subnet.

Comment: There's still the assertion that he's receiving them on the same box in wireshark, though, which suggests they're making it to the box.

Comment: @MarkH that's because Wireshark puts the NIC into [Promiscuous Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode), this allows you to see packets on the wire that would otherwise be ignored/dropped.

Comment: Right, but all broadcast packets are destined for all destinations.  @LiamKelly

Comment: @MarkH at Layer2 yes and Layer3 no. Here it literally the [line in the Linux kernel code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fcadab740480e0e0e9fa9bd272acd409884d431a/net/ipv4/datagram.c#L59) that enforces this.

Comment: Can you explain how that line works? @LiamKelly  I see that the second half seems to check if the socket flag for `SO_BROADCAST` is set, but I'm not sure what sets the `rt` flag for `RTCF_BROADCAST`.  My skepticism is based on the fact that my code below receives broadcast messages without an `EACCES` error and without using any SO_BROADCAST flag.

Comment: @MarkH that is the EACCESS error you get when you try to listen on the broadcast address when you have not set the the SO_BROADCAST flag. So the code says "so you want to access a broadcast address, have you set the SO_BROADCAST socket option? If no then EACCESS"

Comment: No, look at route.c:  in `__mkroute_output` at lines 2389 and 2400 they set the `RTCF_BROADCAST` flag if the *destination* address (`daddr`) is a broadcast address.  No such logic appears in __mkroute_input.  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/route.c#L2389  You need both the RTCF_BROADCAST flag to be set *and* the SO_BROADCAST flag to not be set to trigger EACCES.

Comment: @MarkH that's because you are missing the logic between packets and connection, the original function i sent you was `__ip4_datagram_connect` not a packet parser.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw socket.

````
import struct

SRC_IPv4 = slice(26, 30)
DST_IPv4 = slice(30, 34)

SRC_PORTv4 = slice(34, 36)
DST_PORTv4 = slice(36, 38)

sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(3))
while 1:
    raw, (nic, ptype, *x) = sock.recvfrom(2048)
    if ptype == 2048 and raw[23] == 17:
        src_host = socket.inet_ntoa(raw[SRC_IPv4])
        src_port, = struct.Struct("!H").unpack(raw[SRC_PORTv4])
        dst_host = socket.inet_ntoa(raw[DST_IPv4])
        dst_port, = struct.Struct("!H").unpack(raw[DST_PORTv4])
        print(f'{src_host}:{src_port} => {dst_host}:{dst_port}')```
````

Comment: I have a feeling this is going to be a valid approach, since his packets are likely corrupted.